# Question about holomorphy of a Dirichlet series

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Let $\phi(s)=\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n n^{-s},$ a Dirichlet series. Suppose that $\phi(s)$ is holomorphic at $s_0\in \mathbb{C}$.

My question is: Can we infer that $\phi(s)$ is holomorphic on the half plan $\Re(s)>\Re(s_0)$ ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you meant $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ converges at $s = s_0$, then yes, see what's on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence) : summing by parts $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ converges for every $Re(s) > Re(s_0)$ and is holomorphic.
- Otherwise no, take $a_n = 1$ and $s_0= 1/2$, then $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}$ is holomorphic at $s_0$ but it has a pole at $s=1$

Comment: Thanks. I knew that the statement is true if we replace "holomorphic at $s_0$" by "converges at $s=s_0.$"

Comment: Dear user1952009, If a Dirichlet series $L(s)$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of $s=\sigma_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $L'(s)$ another Dirichlet series which is entire. Can we extended  $L(s)L'(s)$ holomorphically beyond the line $Re(s)=\sigma_0$ ?

Comment: @Adam : Yes, if the derivative is holomorphic then so is the function. What is $L(s)$ in particular ?

Comment: $L(s)=\sum_{n\ge 1} \mu(n)\chi(n)n^{-s}$  ,$s=1$  and $\chi$ a Dirichlet characte

Comment: I did not mean by $L'(s)$ the derivative of $L(s)$! $L'(s)$ another Dirichlet character.

Comment: @Adam I don't see why you think $L'(s) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) \chi(n) n^{-s} \ln n$ is easier. $L(s)$ converges for $Re(s) \ge 1$, but it is complicated to show it converges on $Re(s) = 1$ (as hard as the prime number theorem). The GRH is that it converges on $Re(s) > 1/2$. Now $L(s) = \prod_p (1-\chi(p) p^{-s}) =  \frac{1}{L(s,\chi)}$ where $L(s,\chi) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\chi(n) n^{-s}$ converges (and is analytic) for $Re(s) > 0$ as $\eta(s)$, so $L(s)$ is meromorphic on $Re(s) > 0$.

Comment: Dear user1952009, I did not mean by $L'(s)$ the derivative of $L(s)$,

Comment: Since $L(1,\chi)\neq 0$ then $L(s,\chi)^{-1}$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of $s=1$ then if we multiply $L(s,\chi)^{-1}$ by a $L$-series which is entire. Can we infer that the product can be extended holomorphically beyond the line $Re(s)=1$

Comment: Did you understand my question?

Comment: @Adam What question ? You asked about the convergence and holomorphy of $\frac{1}{L(s,\chi)}$, I gave you some clues

Comment: My question is the following:  For a given entire $L$-series $M(s)$. Can we extended the function $L(s,\chi)^{-1}\times M(s)$ holomorphically beyond the line $Re(s)=1$ ?

Comment: @Adam I doesn't make sense. And $L(s,\chi)$ is meromorphic so $\frac{1}{L(s,\chi)}$ is meromorphic too : it is holomorphic except at isolated points where it has some poles.

Comment: Okay, Thanks...